# Laravel auctions app with time countdown

Tags: laravel, time, countdown

I am working on an bidding app in laravel. So far the idea goes like this:
An admin shall put an item, with time until which bidding shall go (e.g. admin puts tue 25.08 at 14:00 and user who puts highest bid until that time shall get to buy the item). Now, I know how all shall be done, until countdown. I could use some guides on how to actually display the time remaining. I worked on few projects and searched on google and I have no idea how I should display the time; where the time should be saved (DB) etc, how to check in the controller if the time passed or not etc. Basically I would need guides on how to display the time remaining for bidding...

Answer (score 0):

You can save the date/time the auction is ending in the auctions table as an additional column (which you'll probably need anyway), and then compare **Carbon::now()** against that time, that's what's left on the auction. Also you'll need some kind of javascript code checking **current server time** against auction **end server time** if you want to show what's left on real time.